# How to install latest Netplan on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, updates, 22.04, netplan

There's no documentation on the [Netplan.io website](https://netplan.io/) for how to install Netplan, which seems a little odd.

But anyhow, how do I upgrade to the very latest release of Netplan on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: So, give an answer - explain it - isn't that the point of this site?  Instead, saying "What has led you to believe that installing shiny new netplan such an old system is your preferred course of action?" you could say something like "Netplan's behaviour is connected tightly to the version of Ubuntu it runs on, so there's no point in upgrading to the latest version.  this is also why there is no separate installation process for Netplan."

Comment: @DukeDougal What you state in your last comment seems like a good answer really! Would you mind posting it as such?

Comment: I removed the last sentence of your comment, Duke Dougal, as it didn't really add anything to the points you had already made. In any case, I just wanna say that it's okay to ask how to do something that isn't recommended. Who knows - maybe you're in a situation where installing the latest netplan really is the right thing to do. Linux lets us do all sorts of things for fun, science and creativity. In that spirit, I hope we on this site can empower people with information, like *here's why x is a bad idea, but here's how to do x if you really want to*.

Answer (score 6):

netplan.io is a core component of the Ubuntu operating system. As such, it is not recommended to replace the system version with a newer release.  Our policy is to backport the latest stable release of netplan.io to the most recent Ubuntu LTS, so this will be available on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in the near future.

Comment: For awareness: slangasek is a core member of the Ubuntu teams behind the Desktop and other components like Netplan.  This is an authoritative statement *against* updating Netplan yourself because it's such an integral component to the system.

Answer (score 3):

One way to get the latest netplan is build it yourself, following the instructions in the [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/canonical/netplan), which I'm adding below:

1. Install the required packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel ninja-build git
   ```
2. Clone the repository:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/canonical/netplan.git
   ```
3. Go inside the cloned directory:

   ```
   cd netplan
   ```
4. Run the following commands:

   ```
   meson setup build --prefix=/usr [-Db_coverage=true]
   meson compile -C build
   meson test -C build --verbose [TEST_NAME]
   meson install -C build --destdir ../tmproot
   ```

If no errors have occurred, you should have the latest version of netplan installed.

**Note:** I haven't actually tested the above, so proceed at your own risk. I suggest that you first try the above-mentioned procedure in a virtual machine. Only after you make sure that everything works properly apply them in your actual installation.

Comment: In this case, you'll also have the `apt` installed version of `netplan` installed, but the user-compiled one will take precedence, right? 

Comment: I'd guess so, but haven't really tried it, as I said, to be certain...