# 22.04 LTS - timeframe for backport of Netplan version 107?

Tags: netplan

Is there an estimate of when netplan version .107 (in 23.10) will get back-ported to 22.04 LTS

There lots of clean up and advancement with netplan .107 but don't want to risk / mess around trying to make and install locally

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the timeline for an educated guess (since that's all we can do here).

- The latest `netplan` backport for Ubuntu 20.04 was [version 0.104 on March 14, 2022](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/n/netplan.io/netplan.io_0.104-0ubuntu2%7E20.04.4/changelog) - this version of `netplan` was released on February 17, 2022.
- The latest `netplan` backport for Ubuntu 22.04 was [version 0.106.1 on August 24, 2023](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/n/netplan.io/netplan.io_0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.2/changelog) - this version of `netplan` was released on May 26, 2023.

So this gives a period of 1-3 months for the newer `netplan` version to be backported.

Since the latest version 0.107.1 of `netplan` was released on December 14, 2023, it would be reasonable to assume that a backport would come here during March 2024.

But as mentioned, this is merely an educated guess from my part. However, [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/1507309/1066942) from one of the developers seem to support the above.

Comment: Thanks Artur for the  detailed response - that makes sense, as you say it seems like it is in the works and hopefully will see similar turnaround time as previously